# Reading value from JSON string Scala using ScalaJson

Tags: scala

I have a JSON response as follow

```
{
  ......,

  "phoneNumbers":[
   {
    "info":[

  ],
  "phoneNumber":"1234567890",
  "phoneNumberType":"HOME_NUMBER"
 },
 {
  "info":[

  ],
  "phoneNumber":"9876543210",
  "phoneNumberType":"WORK_NUMBER"
 },
 {
  "info":[

  ],
  "phoneNumber":"7418529630",
  "phoneNumberType":"MOBILE_NUMBER"
 }
],

.......

}
```

I need to extract mobile number and I try like this

```
  val jsonBody = Json.parse(phoneListResponse.body)
  val phoneList: Seq[JsValue] = (jsonBody \\ "phoneNumbers")
  val mobileNodes: Seq[JsValue] = phoneList.filter(number => {
   (number \\ "phoneNumberType").head.asInstanceOf[JsString].value == "MOBILE_NUMBER"
  })
  (mobileNodes.head \\ "phoneNumber").head.asInstanceOf[JsString].value
```

But my mobileNodes is empty. Any suggestion?

Comment: What json lib are you using? That could be a number of them (I've lost count of how many json libs Scala+Java has.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Play-json`

```
val phoneList: Seq[String] = 
 ((jsonBody \\ "phoneNumbers")(0).as[List[JsValue]])
 .filter(x => (x \ "phoneNumberType").as[String] == "MOBILE_NUMBER")
 .map(x => (x \ "phoneNumber").as[String])
```

**REPL output**

```
scala>  ((json \\ "phoneNumbers")(0).as[List[JsValue]]).foreach(println)
{"info":[],"phoneNumber":"1234567890","phoneNumberType":"HOME_NUMBER"}
{"info":[],"phoneNumber":"9876543210","phoneNumberType":"WORK_NUMBER"}
{"info":[],"phoneNumber":"7418529630","phoneNumberType":"MOBILE_NUMBER"}

scala>  ((json \\ "phoneNumbers")(0).as[List[JsValue]]).filter(x => (x \ "phoneNumberType").as[String] == "MOBILE_NUMBER")
res31: List[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List({"info":[],"phoneNumber":"7418529630","phoneNumberType":"MOBILE_NUMBER"})

scala>  ((json \\ "phoneNumbers")(0).as[List[JsValue]]).filter(x => (x \ "phoneNumberType").as[String] == "MOBILE_NUMBER").map(x => (x \ "phoneNumber").as[String])
res32: List[String] = List(7418529630)
```

Comment: Still phoneList is empty.

Comment: @αƞjiβ here is the repl output for step wise execution

Comment: @αƞjiβ I have edited the answer Please notice the (0)